# Set PATH in .bashrc depending on shell

Tags: linux, bash, path, bashrc

I have a user `switcher` that has different use-cases. It's `PATH` should depend on whether the current shell is restricted or not. Thus I've added to the end of `/home/switcher/.bashrc`:

```
[[ $- == *r* ]] && PATH='' && echo 'restricted' || echo 'unrestricted'
```

Yet it doesn't work as expected when switching users:

```
root@host:~$ sudo -u switcher rbash
unrestricted
switcher@host:~$ echo $PATH
/home/switcher/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
switcher@host:~$ echo $- $SHELL
himrBHs /usr/sbin/nologin
```

This tells me that `.bashrc` was in fact executed but apparently outside `rbash`. What am I missing here? What do I need to change so that `PATH=''` is set when executing `rbash` but not in `bash`?

Note that having different users for the different use-cases unfortunately isn't an option for me.

Comment: You can't set / change `PATH` *in* restricted bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html (But you can probably use `env` to start the restricted bash with a different `PATH`.)

Comment: @TomYan From the page you linked to: "These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read". It's absolutely possible to change `PATH` from within `.bashrc` processed automatically by a restricted `bash`. The restrictions kick in later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tests show that `r` appears in `$-` after `rbash` reads `~/.bashrc`, as if the shell was not restricted during processing the file. This corresponds to what the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) says about restrictions:

> These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.

One of the restrictions is the inability to change `PATH`. Since you do want to change `PATH`, it's actually good for your case the restrictions are enforced later. It seems `r` in `$-` indicates that the shell is effectively restricted at the moment. You want to detect if it's *going to be* effectively restricted. You cannot use `$-` for this.

There is a mechanism designed deliberately for what you need to do. It's in [`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) [emphasis mine]:

> `restricted_shell`
>
> The shell sets this option if it is started in restricted mode […]. The value may not be changed. This is not reset when the startup files are executed, **allowing the startup files to discover whether or not a shell is restricted**.

Use it like this:

```
shopt -q restricted_shell && PATH='' && echo 'restricted' || echo 'unrestricted'
```

Or better:

```
if shopt -q restricted_shell; then
   PATH=''
   echo 'restricted'
else
   echo 'unrestricted'
fi
```

The latter is better because the second `echo` depends only on the exit status from `shopt`. For comparison: in the former snippet (and in your original code) failing first `echo` would trigger the second `echo`. With `echo`s this seems marginal, irrelevant or harmless, but if you add more commands then a line with many `&&` and `||` may surprise you if one of them fails unexpectedly.

Also note that printing anything from `.bashrc` will break `scp` and similar software ([even printing to stderr may](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29608629/10765659)), unless [your `.bashrc` is smart enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257571/108618).

Comment: This answer is perfect! You're awesome, thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and research.
I only added the `echo`s for debugging purposes, I won't use them in the final solution. But your notes are appreciated regardless.